# where are the keyboards shotcuts are defined (in which configuration file)

Tags: linux

when we do set -o ignoreof
it will disable the working of ctrl+D
can u please confirm which file will effected with this command .
also i want to assign that whenever i will press space bar my gnome-terminal will open
how can it is possible .
whre keyboard shotcuts working are placed any designation file ???
thanks in advance 
sunil

Answer (score 2):

Global keybindings are in `System`|`Preferences`|`Keyboard Shortcuts`. Application-specific keybindings will be in an application-specific location. Terminal control sequences can be viewed/set with `stty`. bash keybindings are configured in `~/.inputrc`; see the **READLINE** section of the `bash(1)` man page for details.

Comment: application specific ? could u pls elaborate by example

Comment: In geany they're in `Edit`|`Preferences`|`Keybindings`. In GIMP they're in `Edit`|`Keyboard Shortcuts`.